# Two dates combination showing as shortdate in textbox in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a partial view which has the value of startdate -enddate.

I have startdate and enddate properties in model as datetime. When data is coming from webapi it is binding with time. But I need as 01/01/2015 - 30/12/2015. But it is displaying as 01/01/2015 12:00:00 AM to 30/12/2015 12:00:00 AM.

Can anybody help me

Comment: Please post the corresponding view and model code. You most probably only need to format the two date properties...

Comment: Partial view data is loading with moment.min.js and in model  public DateTime? StartDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }  public DateTime? EndDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

Comment: In main view @Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/DateRangePicker.cshtml", null)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StartDate)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EndDate)

Comment: Finally i got solution. Thanks for responding to my question

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@item.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
```

or you could use the [DisplayFormat] attribute on your view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set }
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)
```